For including in the calculations after cloud masking done in the image
First part of the code creating the test variables.
var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3; // pushes "1" 3 spaces to the left 001000
var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;  // pushes "1" 5 spaces to the left 0100000
The bitwiseAnd() function tests the validity of that bit against a byte to see if the "bit" is true in the full byte.
000000000000 // Image QA    Test against this
000000001000 // cloudShadowBitMask
000000000000 // result false.  No bit matches.  So no cloud Shadow
000000100000 // cloudsBitMask
000000000000 // result false.  No bit matches.  So no cloud
As you then supply this to your mask any pixel that doesn't equal 0 to both these tests, will be masked in your final image and not be used in any subsequent calculations.
But I want to use images after masked in my subsequent calculations. How to do? Is it possible?
